# Перестал открываться сайт, админка работает

Tags: opencart

подскажите перестал открываться сайт 500 Internal server error, админка работает корректно

Куда смотреть ?

Comment: В логи сайта, очевидно

Answer (score 1):

5хх это ошибки сервера, смотрите лог Nginx/Apache, смотря что у Вас на сервере/хостинге установлено.

вообще подобное может быть из-за:

- установленного модуля
- установленного модификатора
- вас взломали либо сайт заражён вирусом